# Enable CORS with wamp on windows 8

Tags: apache, cross-domain, wamp, cors

I have a cross domain request problem with an application I'm doing. I really spent hours looking for a solution on how to enable CORS with wamp (localhost) but nothing worked for me.

I have Apache 2.4.9 on Windows 8.1. I have enable the headers, I tried to put

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```

in a .htaccess and in the http.conf as well as countless other variations.

If anyone had a solution that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and i solved it with these 3 steps:

**1)** in Apache config file (for me the path was C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf\httpd.conf) 
add the line:
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
in the content of the `<Directory>` tag:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
</Directory>
```

**2)** activate the "headers_module" in apache's modules (it will also restart your apache server, effectively applying the change made in step 1)

**3)** clear your browser cache (I am using chrome and i was told the best way to "hard clear" the cache was to go in the developper tools -> Networks tab -> right click -> clear browser cache) 
(by the way, clearing the browser cache is often useful when debugging in chrome)

Now it should work. Good luck !

Answer (score 16):

You must also activate the Apache Headers module.

Using the wampmanager menus do this :-

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Apache modules -> headers_module
```

Make sure this is ticked, if its not, click that menu item and wait a few seconds while WampServer restarts Apache.

Comment: After more then an hour of searching why I had `Image from origin '...' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.` and multiple `.htaccess` and other useless solutions, this is the correct one for me.

Comment: trying to load a font from S3 and this doesn't work