# wamp server, upload file from taken photo with phone camera not working

Tags: html, forms, file-upload, android-camera, wamp

I have a file upload.php contains a form to upload photo and a short version code to check in submit.php, something like this :

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['img'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['img'];
    $fileName = $file['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];

    echo $fileTmpName;
    echo $fileName;
}
?>
```

if I put the upload.php and that submit.php on my website server, then I run it either via computer's browser or phone's browser, it did show the text coming from the two echos in the script. Also, if I use the phone camera then take a photo (so the uploaded file is not by clicking a file in the phone's file explorer), the two echos work as expected.

I have Wamp Server PHP Version:7.3.21 installed in my computer.
So, I put the upload.php and the submit.php in the www directory inside the wamp folder in drive C of my computer.

Either from computer browser or from phone browser, when I upload a jpg photo **by browsing the file explorer then choose a file**, it did show both echos. The echo of $fileTmpName, show on the page something like this `C:\wamp64\tmp\php6D61.tmp` and the echo of $fileName, show on the page something like this `IMG20211106142435.jpg`.

BUT, if I upload the photo **by using the phone camera app**, it didn't echo the $fileTmpName, it only echo the $fileName; which is something like `1701272161573433982345.jpg`.  It's just as if the $fileTmpName is empty.

My question:
What did I do wrong ?
Is there a setting in Wamp Server which I should do to allow upload a photo by taking a photo with phone camera app ?

---

I found a stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391328/file-upload-works-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile-using-camera) which answer is accepted.
So I follow the instruction in another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058104/enable-cors-with-wamp-on-windows-8) which provided in that accepted answer. Still no luck.