# Ajax to wampserver localhost from cross domain website console

Tags: jquery, ajax, wampserver

I'm using this code and it's not working:

```
myURL = "http://localhost/index.html";
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET', 
  url: myURL, 
  success: function(data) { 
    console.log(data); 
  }, 
  async: false
});
```

Or

```
myURL = "http://127.0.1.1/index.html";
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET', 
  url: myURL, 
  success: function(data) { 
    console.log(data); 
  }, 
  async: false
});
```

It works when I'm in a local webpage, but when I'm in a cross domain website (like google), I cannot ajax my file at the localhost.

Is there a way to work around this? Thank you.

Comment: 1) remove `async: false` 2) if you want this to work cross domain you'll need to change the response from your server to include CORS headers

Comment: Thank you for the comment. How can I include CORS header? Thank you very much :), I'll search for it but a quick answer is appreciated :)

Comment: First hit in google for `WAMP server cors`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058104/enable-cors-with-wamp-on-windows-8

Comment: Thank you man, have a nice day !